# systemctl mavproxy

Tags: systemctl

Всем привет , подскажите как офорить автозапуск mavproxy , вот к примеру строчка

```
mavproxy.py --master=/dev/ttyAMA0 --out 192.168.x.x:14550 --aircraft MyCopter
```

отлично работает , весь мавлинк поступает на ай-пи, можно ловить по UDP в МишнПланер а если оформляю

```
[Unit]
# описание
Description=MYSTART
# здесь используется ключи времени с указанием цели или другой службы
After=default.target

[Service]
# от какого пользователя запускать службу, не обязательно
User=pi
# перезапуск службы, не обязательно
Restart=on-failure
# выполняемая команда
ExecStart=echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc&&mavproxy.py --master=/dev/ttyAMA0 --out 192.168.x.x:14550 --daemon

[Install]
# здесь используется ключи времени с указанием цели или другой службы
WantedBy=default.target
```

...то юнит запускается , но трансляция на АйПи адрес не происходит...

[image: ответ на запрос по СТАТУС]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: `echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc` — у вас при каждом запуске новая строка в файл добавляется. и каждая новая строка добавляет один и тот же кусок в переменную PATH. через некоторое время что-то у вас там закончится. или место на блочном устройстве, или допустимая длина значения переменной окружения.

Comment: да но если я убераю первую часть кода(присвоение) , то сразу получаю - (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос
юнит должен вглядить так...

```
[Unit]
Description=Mavproxy runner
After=default.target

[Service]
Restart=on-failure
ExecStart=su - pi -c "cd ~pi; screen -L -dmS mavbarn ~pi/[вашБашСкрипт].sh"

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

все прекрасно работает и запускается с пол пинка))